# Pass parameter to validator - fluent validation

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have a validator that I use for both an insert, and an update. One of the checks I do is to see if what is being inserted already exists. The code for the validator is:

```
public GrapeColourValidator(IGrapeRepository grapeRepository)
        {
            _grapeRepository = grapeRepository;

            RuleFor(x => x.Colour)
                .NotEmpty()
                .WithMessage("Colour is required")
                .MaximumLength(_maxLength)
                .WithMessage($"Colour cannot be more that {_maxLength} characters");

            RuleFor(x => x)
                .MustAsync(async (grapeColour, context, cancellation) =>
                {
                    return await GrapeColourExists(grapeColour.Colour).ConfigureAwait(false);
                })
                .WithMessage($"Grape colour already exists");
        }

        private async Task<bool> GrapeColourExists(string grapeColour)
        {
            var colourResult = await _grapeRepository.GetByColour(grapeColour).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return !colourResult.Any(x => x.Colour == grapeColour);
        }
```

The issue with this is that it runs for Update also, so the colour will definitely exists. What I want to do is pass a parameter, so I could do something like:

```
if(isInsert)
            {
                RuleFor(x => x)
                .MustAsync(async (grapeColour, context, cancellation) =>
                {
                    return await GrapeColourExists(grapeColour.Colour).ConfigureAwait(false);
                })
                .WithMessage($"Grape colour already exists");
            }
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually accomplish this with a property on the view model I am validating. Basically, you need a flag on the view model indicating whether it represents "new" or "existing" data.

If you have a numeric identifier (which includes Guid's) just test for the default value of the Id:

```
// For int identifiers:
public class ViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public bool IsNew => Id == default(int);
}

// For GUID identifiers:
public class ViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public bool IsNew => Id == default(Guid );
}
```

And then add a `When(...)` clause to the validation rule:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Property)
    .Must(...)
    .When(x => x.IsNew);
```

The downside with testing a view model property is that it could be vulnerable to request tampering. Someone can POST a non default Guid or int in the request and make the validator think it is validating a persisted object.

Then again, you should be authenticating and authorizing every request, as well as checking anti-forgery tokens.

Comment: Hmmm, not over the moon with that, but it certainly gets me out of the predicament I put myself in. Cheers

Comment: @Keith: I felt the same way when I first came up with this solution. I haven't found anything better unless you want to create concrete classes for each use case - which is an option. You could write a CreateFooValidator and UpdateFooValidator. That would be an option. But using the same view models in both use cases presents a challenge with deciding which validator to create.

Answer (score 1):

3 years too late, but for anyone wondering how to do this - you can use RootContextData https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/advanced.html#root-context-data

```
var context = ValidationContext<yourTypeHere>(request);
context.RootContextData["IsUpdate"] = true;
validator.Validate(context);
```

and then in your validator you can get the IsUpdate value out of the context

```
context.RootContextData.TryGetValue("IsUpdate", out var IsUpdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have 3 classes:

1. GrapeColourValidator: This class will contain validations needed for Create and Update
2. GrapeColourCreateValidator: This class inherits from GrapeColourValidator and contains only the validations for Creating the resource.
3. GrapeColourUpdateValidator: This class inherits from GrapeColourValidator and contains only the validations for Updating the resource.

And then in your Controller you can inyect the 2 validators and use them when needed.